# Cannot open Firefox and Waterfox at the same time

Tags: firefox, waterfox

I have a Windows 7 64 bit machine. I've installed [Waterfox](http://www.waterfoxproject.org/index.php) , the 64 bit version of Firefox, as well as Firefox.

When one of the browsers is open, and I click to open the other one, a new window opens in the already opened browser instead. I'm not able to open the two browsers at the same time.

Does anyone know the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Waterfox website](http://www.waterfoxproject.org/download.php):

```
Waterfox shares the same profile data that Firefox does.
```

Thus, what you want to do is starting a new instance of Waterfox (or Firefox), or create a different profile. Please take a look at [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile) for information on how to do that using `-no-remote` and `-P` options.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the previous suggestion of using profiles, you also can use a portable version of Waterfox.

Portable versions of Waterfox (or other ff flavors) have the profile folder (\user) under its main folder, so it is independent of others browsers.

Also it is good to avoid the use of the default FF profile folder because you can have problems with previous extensions and upgrades of Firefox.

Last versions of FF (such as 57) are not compatible anymore with XUL extensions whereas Waterfox is still compatible with XUL extensions but also with the new webextensions.